# Appending new frames to an existing DICOM file

Tags: dicom, gdcm

I am working with DCMTK to modify an input DICOM file.

This is a Multi-Frame DICOM file on my disk. I need to add new frames into the PixelData element, and save the output using the same input filename.

The restriction is that I can not load the whole PixelData in memory. I would like to append new frame to the end of DICOM file, directly. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you are using DCMTK, if instead you were using GDCM, you could simply instantiate the FileStreamer class and append any Pixel Data chunk you would like:

See [FileStreamer](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1FileStreamer.html) documentation.